# How to insert only added value in TextBox on DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net

when I add value on textbox this symbol `,` is with the text as if i add text `GO` in textbox. I found that the text `GO,` inserted in Database. SO why this symbol `,` inserted with the textbox text .

```
protected void Btn_ElarabyHome_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    var Comment = (TextBox)((ImageButton)sender).Parent.FindControl("txt_ElarabyHome");

    ftier.Addcomment(LBLEhomePID.Text, LoggedUserID, txt_ElarabyHome.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, false);
    Comment.Text = string.Empty;
    ModelExtenderPost.Show();        
}


 public bool Addcomment(string Post_ID, string User_ID, string Comment_Content, DateTime Comment_Add_Date, DateTime Comment_Last_Date, bool Comment_Flag)
{

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.Insertintocomments");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Post_ID", Post_ID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_ID", User_ID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment_Content", Comment_Content);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment_Add_Date", Comment_Add_Date);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment_Last_Date", Comment_Last_Date);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment_Flag", Comment_Flag);

    return DBHelper.Instance().Insert(cmd);
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPElarabyHome" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:Panel ID="UPElarabHome" runat="server" DefaultButton="Btn_ElarabyHome">
       <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_ElarabyHome" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" EnableViewState="false" CssClass="comment-tabs2" ValidationGroup="ElarabyHome"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:ImageButton ID="Btn_ElarabyHome" CommandName="ElarabyHome" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ElarabyHome" OnClick="Btn_ElarabyHome_Click" Style="display: none" />
       <asp:Label ID="LBLEhomePID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Post_ID")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Btn_ElarabyHome" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Where is the part where you insert in DB?

Comment: @skdeveloper given code seems to be ok, can you update the question with `Insertintocomments` SQL code as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
public bool Addcomment(string Post_ID, string User_ID, string Comment_Content, DateTime Comment_Add_Date, DateTime Comment_Last_Date, bool Comment_Flag)
{

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.Insertintocomments");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Post_ID", Post_ID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_ID", User_ID);
    Comment_Content = Comment_Content.Contains(",") ? Comment_Content.Replace(",", null) : Comment_Content;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment_Content", Comment_Content);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment_Add_Date", Comment_Add_Date);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment_Last_Date", Comment_Last_Date);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment_Flag", Comment_Flag);

    return DBHelper.Instance().Insert(cmd);
}
```

Comment: If the problem comes from the stored procedure it won't solve anything